# need to encode/escape html string using java and decode the html string in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

Technology used: Spring MVC.

I have html string as shown below:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>hello</h2>
      <h2>world</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

**What I need?**

1. Store this html string in a model object and send to jsp (this should work this way)
2. Using jsp tag, store html string in a hidden html input field (recommend if any other approach is available)
3. Access the value present in hidden field in javascript (recommend if any other approach is available)

**Problem I'm facing right now?**

1. Store this html string in a model object and send to jsp
2. Store html string into hidden html input field.

**Problem:** but the html content gets rendered in the ui, so i'm not able to go ahead

I think I need to encode html string in java and decode it in javascript.

Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: You could try using `URLEncoder`

Comment: @Thomas instead i used different basic way. please see my updated answer. i'm not sure whether this is recommended, but i find it helpful

Comment: Hmm, that might work but you'll still have to be careful because you'd have to keep in mind the structure of the html fits the page's structure. Otherwise you could accidentially break the page (without embedding it you could strip unwanted parts from the HTML before (re)adding it to the page. Additionally you should make sure no malicious code can be added to the HTML despite the approach you use to pass it to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

i stored the html content in the model jsp page within `<div>` with `style hidden`. Then accessed the div content in javascript. i did not face encoding problem in this approach, because its obvious that browser renders it but doesn't display. Thank you